# M2CRYPTO generating RSA key pair with automotically passphrase

Tags: python

I am using this "key = RSA.gen_key(2048, 65537,genPass)" for RSA key generation,
It is asking to enter a passphrase.
How can i generate it without passphrase from user?and put some known passphrase automaticlly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Key generation does not require a password.  It is required only when you save to file.  If you want to do so automatically, you can provide a password generator as the callback to the save_key method.

```
>>> import M2Crypto
>>> rsaKey = M2Crypto.RSA.gen_key(2048, 65537)
.........................+++
................................+++
>>> def passwordCallback(*args, **kwds):
...     return 'mypassword'
... 
>>> rsaKey.save_key('/tmp/test.pem')
Enter passphrase:
Verify passphrase:
0
>>> rsaKey.save_key('/tmp/test.pem', callback=passwordCallback)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got the RSA module [from PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rsa) then it should be

```
import rsa
rsa.gen_keys(<key size in bits>)
```

Comment: i need to insert passphrase (not from user,but automatically)